# Is there a way to automatically extract slides out of a video?

Tags: video, slide, takesscreenshot

the MVP that would satisfy my needs would be something scanning a video and (semi)intelligently extract the whole screen every time it changes (new slide appears)

The ideal tool would be configurable to only take a picture of a selected are.

I found many ways to pick stills from a video, but nothing looking for slides...or just looking for something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you need **frame differencing**. It's not obvious what is your programming language but make sure it allows you to take screen shots of the video object. If the current grabbed pixels are **different** from previously grabbed image then you have a new slide. Use a **For** loop to check the **equality** of both images' pixels.

Comment: I have built a python package for this called `slide-extractor` which does exactly what you are trying to do. You can see it here https://pypi.org/project/slide-extractor/1.0.0 . You can also take inspiration from its source code if you want to make something like this on your own

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at u2Docs. https://www.u2docs.com  It was implemented by comparing frames from video and capturing them.

Answer (score 1):

You can give https://reccap.it a shot. It doesn't directly output a slide deck file. But it's pretty good at detecting every slide and snapshotting it.

Here is an example: https://reccap.it/recaps/open-pretrained-transformers-susan-zhang-stanford-mlsys-77-fd41161abaed477787bff4393c4d98b5

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` tool can do this by differencing frames in the video. However, for this to work, you need to have a video consisting only of slides, or you need to crop a part of whole video frame if the video has a moving object, like a person's camera, so only the slide is visible. Otherwise, `ffmpeg` can capture the whole video frames.

Install ffmpeg:

```bash
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Then, capture differentiated frames into `extracted_imgs` folder, as an example:

```bash
ffmpeg -i my_video.mp4 -filter_complex "select=gt(scene\,0.01)" "extracted_imgs/%04d.jpg" -vsync drop -vb 20M
```

Here, you can change `0.01` to adjust how to difference the frames, more sensitively or more coarsely.